# Trying to create a type checker util but cannot without getting a type error

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a util function that I want to use that will return a boolean stating whether a value equals a certain type:

```
const valueIsOfType = <T>(value: T, type: string):boolean => typeof(value) === type ? true : false;
```

However, when I use it in my code as a conditional for a ternary operator, like this:

```
const foo: string | JSX.Element = "bar";

return valueIsOfType(title, "string") ? truncateText(title, 18) : title;
```

**Note**: function declaration for `truncateText(text, maxLength)`;

```
const truncateText = (text: string, maxLength: number):string => {
    if(text.length >= maxLength) return text.slice(0, maxLength) + "..."
    else return text;
};
```

I get the following type error on the line invoking `valueIsOf`:

> "Argument of type 'string | JSX.Element' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
> Type 'JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'string'."

I presume this is happening because TypeScipt cannot tell that I am checking the type with this function, so it fires a type error to prevent a mismatched type dealing with `truncateText;`.

Is there a way I can use this util without having to manually do `typeof(value) === type ? true : false;` for every type I want to check? I'd like to use this util or something like this for readability purposes.

Comment: Can you make sure your code constitutes a [mcve]?  Where are you getting the error, specifically?

Comment: @jcalz The error is on the lining invoking `valueIsOfType`. Otherwise, I'm not really sure what's missing for my question tbh; I provided everything needed to understand the function, in a minimalistic way where the functions can be easily understood without having to look at the actual code its related to.

Comment: The idea of a [mcve] is that someone can drop it into their own IDE (e.g., [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?)) and demonstrate the problem you're talking about for themselves.  If I do that, the only errors that show up are ones about missing declarations like `doSomethingWithString()`.  I can *guess* what you're trying to do, but you're not showing it.

Comment: By the way, in `typeof value === type ? true : false` the ternary can be omitted.  `typeof value === type` will already be either `true` or `false`.

Comment: @jcalz that makes sense, however I would imagine that adding the actual function instead of `doSomethingIfString()` would defeat the "minimalistic" part because then I'd have to explain that function as well, even though its not necessarily integral to understanding the problem. Regardless, I have updated my question to hopefully add clarity

Comment: I've linked to the [mcve] doc twice before (now three times) and it describes "minimal" as "Minimal – Use as little code as possible *that still produces the same problem*" (emphasis mine).  If you do not give enough code to reproduce the issue, then it's too minimal.  Otherwise, "minimal" would just mean "don't post any code", which is not the point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to guess that you want `valueIsOfType()` to act as a [user-defined type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards), where the compiler sees the `boolean` return value as evidence that one of its parameters is or is not of a certain type.  If so, you need the return type to be annotated as a *type predicate* like `value is string`.

The compiler does not see `typeof value === type` and automatically *infer* that the function itself is a type guard.  There's an open issue, [microsoft/TypeScript#16069](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16069), asking for such a feature, but for now it's not part of the language.

In any case, you can make a generic version `valueIsOfType()` function which should hopefully cover the full range of possible results of the JavaScript `typeof` operator and the implications for the tested object:

```
interface TypeofResults {
    string: string,
    number: number,
    bigint: bigint,
    boolean: boolean,
    symbol: symbol,
    undefined: undefined,
    object: object | null,
    function: Function
}

const valueIsOfType =
    <K extends keyof TypeofResults>(value: any, type: K): value is TypeofResults[K] =>
        typeof value === type
```

The `TypeofResults` interface serves as a mapping from results of `typeof` and the types guarded.  Most of those are straightforward as the TypeScript type name is the same as the value returned from `typeof`.  A few are different... if `typeof value === "object"` then `value` is either of the TypeScript `object` type, *or* it's `null`, which is not considered assignable to `object`.  And TypeScript's unspecified function type is called `Function` with a capital `F`.

The `valueIsOfType()` function is generic in `K`, the type of the `type` parameter, and the return type is a type predicate narrowing the `value` parameter from `any` (which does not need to be generic) to the corresponding property type from `TypeofResults`.  So if you call `valueIsOfType(anyValue, "string")`, the return type will be the type predicate `anyValue is string`.

You can see that it works:

```
function test(foo: string | number | Date) {
    if (valueIsOfType(foo, "string")) {
        console.log(foo.toUpperCase()); // foo seen to be string here
    } else if (valueIsOfType(foo, "number")) {
        console.log(foo.toFixed(2)); // foo seen to be number here
    } else {
        console.log(foo.toUTCString()) // foo seen to be Date here
    }
}

test("hello"); // HELLO
test(Math.PI); // 3.14
test(new Date()); // Sat, 12 Sep 2020 02:22:01 GMT
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.0.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoE8AOED2MBKEAzgK4A2YRyA3gFDIPJFhSgDmAXEy+wDT2MQJALYAjaFyFjo-RslHA2oMFwVLwsxqJw4yEOCFU69BzQyLoxurhatkzyEiAAmEGKAjOuT1+5CeHHFEAKwgEFWQg0PDkAB9kITJ7AQYYJ3DgHENkADF0sEyQZFoAX1paBCzmZAA3ODISCABJIgB5GAxsZABeFOQAHgBpZAgAD0gXKgBrCHQ8NCxcAmJySgA+AAo6hoguA3ReZDBFrkGASi5txuRgKk6lwlIKIgBtQYBdHrW+uWPseauKG6wKOi3KtDSIAyWSOxDAGxgOhsPBAbDiCRE4ig6IAInBIGcaH1gDBkFt6o0Wu17gidIcAETMVio+lnQl0ORySogIi6CAAOjIODYtJw-LAOAAqphsFAAMJwIgQDZsgDcfRKIzISpupPJOypHUWooZUixrPZP0Y3N5ekFwtF4pwOWAo08GwATGqNVqdRzOQwbXz7SLEWKJZLUHKAMookVsjWlcqQZgbekACwgSRwrNVyAA9PnkAAJACiABly61aCn4QBZfHp-kABSaZzzheQAGZ+QBGAAsNbhG38AHdkHjICr2wWi9H8Ydex7kNGIJhkB6AAxb5Dbjgej0cTe95AAcTrqFoQA)